# state not updating through components when using React Context and React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-context, react-hook-form

I'm using a context provider (FormProvider) to manage form data across multiple form components (using React Hook Form). The problem is that even though I update the form data within the context using setFormData, the updated data is not reflected in the components that consume this context.

I need to have one parent component to handle and display the forms based on certain conditions, and just one submit button, thats why I chose react context to handle and persist the form states through them.

```
// form-context.js

import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const FormContext = createContext({});

export const FormProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

  const updateFormData = (data) => {
    console.log("data do form passados para o contexto", data);
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, ...data }));
  };

  console.log("formdata no contexto:", formData);

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ formData, updateFormData }}>{children}</FormContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useFormContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(FormContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useFormContext must be used within the FormProvider");
  }
  return context;
};
```

```
// parent form component (I've cut non related parts of the code)

import { FormProvider, useFormContext } from "src/contexts/form-context";

const FormMenus = () => {
  const { formData } = useFormContext();

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("formData antes do envio:", formData); // Here, formData is always empty, as well as its initial state...

      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/member/", formData);
      console.log("Resposta do servidor:", response.data);
      setIsSuccessModalOpen(true); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error when sending form data:", error);
 
    }
  };



  return (
    <FormProvider>
      <div sx={{ bgColor: "neutral.200" }}>

        <Button
          onClick={handleSubmit}
          variant="contained"
          color="success"
          sx={{ m: 1, mr: 2, mt: 2 }}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>

      </div>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};

export default FormMenus;
```

I have tried many many stuff, I was not even using react hook form, thinking that the problem could be in the way I was handling the form states just using useState hook....

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need to move your FormProvider element to the parent component of FormMenus.  the issue is that you're trying to access the contents of the context from inside the same component that creates the provider for said context.

straight from the docs:

> useContext returns the context value for the calling component. It is
> determined as the value passed to the closest SomeContext.Provider
> **above the calling component** in the tree. If there is no such provider,
> then the returned value will be the defaultValue you have passed to
> createContext for that context.

https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext

example:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <FormProvider>
            <ChildComponent/>
        </FormProvider>
    )
}
const ChildComponent = () => {
    const { formData } = useFormContext();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        console.log(formData);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```